# How to embed gnome-terminal in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

I am making a simple Python program which I want to run gnome terminal into it.
I've done some research and I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7331836/16775594), but I want to embed gnome terminal not xterm. The linked question's answer uses `xterm -into` but `gnome-terminal` does not seem to have a comparable option.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. This also doesn't appear to have anything with [tag:bash] to do. I have removed these spurious tags.

Comment: Alright thanks 

Comment: Anyway, the obvious solution is to replace the `xterm` call in the other question with a `gnome-terminal` command line. The available options obviously differ but that's the gist of it (though using `subprocess` instead of `system` would be an improvement).

Comment: I did it but apparently there is no option for gnome terminal to embed it to other applications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581791/embed-a-konsole-or-gnome-terminal-inside-a-tkinter-frame appears to ask the same question, but it doesn't have a (proper) answer.

Comment: Running `gnome-terminal --help-all` shows a list of all the options. Judging by what's there, there isn't any simple way to embed `gnome-terminal` in a `tkinter` window.  However, maybe you run the terminal (I mean like `bash`, `sh`, etc.) in a process, and change it's stdin and stdout so that they go to your program...

Answer (score 1):

gnome-terminal is a GTK app, Tkinter creates TCL app: both libraries will interact with the underlying window manager in *very* different ways and likely with some conflict (in handling/consuming input events, for example).

Since the embed option does not exist, to start with, I´d say this is not feasible but for setting a raw framebuffer inside the tkinter app, and somehow routing the gnome-terminal to use an emulated/contained window manager in that framebuffer - that would be at least an order of magnitude more complex than any answer you might be looking for.

Instead, if you want to give the user of your app a raw shell in a terminal app, and can't live with simply popping it up in another window, is to re-do your application using GTK instead of tkinter, and check in the gnome-terminal development docs/source code if the main terminal widget can be used stand-alone in another app.

Comment: And for information on how to embed a terminal in a Gtk window, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60454326/16775594).